# Error "Value Cannot be null" when using ReadObject of NetDataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm trying to use NetDataContractSerializer to deserialize an XML that was serialized by NetDataContractSerializer too.

I am using NetDataContractSerializer and not DataContractSerializer because I'm serializing my class that includes some multi-dimensional array.
I validated the XML file with some W3 validator and it passed.

This is the deserializing part

```
using (FileStream reader = new FileStream(filePath,FileMode.Open))
            {
                NetDataContractSerializer ser = new NetDataContractSerializer();
                Universe loadedUniverse = (Universe)ser.ReadObject(reader);
            }
```

And this is the exception I get

> Value cannot be null. parameter: Source

I Tried to debug it deep inside but didn't understand what exactly went wrong there.
It seems like the FileStream is getting to the file's content correctly.

Also tried using XmlReader instead of FileStream, got the same error. Using XmlReader I saw that it's getting the type of the serialized class good as well, so I'm ruling out that the file is not found or something like that.

This is the serializing part of the code

```
NetDataContractSerializer ser =
            new NetDataContractSerializer();

        using (FileStream file = new FileStream(target, FileMode.Create))
        {
            ser.WriteObject(file, universe);
        }
```

[Here is the xml file](http://justpaste.it/lou9) (Sorry couldn't find online XML sharing tool)

Is there anything wrong with the way I'm trying to approach this?
Will be grateful for your help!

Comment: What is the exact value of filePath?

Comment: the value of filePath is save.xml. It's found in the directory as the exe

Answer (score 1):

Try code below.  I added the XML line one into my file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication33
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement m_AllCells = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "AllCells").FirstOrDefault();
            AllCells allCells = new AllCells(m_AllCells); 
        }

    }
    public class AllCells
    {
        public int size {get;set;}
        public int version {get;set;}
        public Items items { get; set; }

        public AllCells(XElement m_AllCells)
        {
            size = int.Parse(m_AllCells.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "_size").FirstOrDefault().Value);
            version = int.Parse(m_AllCells.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "_version").FirstOrDefault().Value);

            XElement childItem = m_AllCells.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "_items").FirstOrDefault();
            if (childItem != null)
            {
                items = new Items(childItem);
            }
        }
    }
    public class Items
    {
        public int? iD { get; set; }
        public int? size { get; set; }
        public List<Cell> cells {get; set;}
        public Items(XElement items)
        {
            XAttribute newId = items.Attributes().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Id").FirstOrDefault();
            if (newId == null)
            {
                iD = null;
            }
            else
            {
                iD = int.Parse(newId.Value);
            }
            XAttribute newSize = items.Attributes().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Size").FirstOrDefault();
            if (newSize == null)
            {
                size = null;
            }
            else
            {
                size = int.Parse(newSize.Value);
            }
            List<XElement> childCells = items.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Cell").ToList();
            if (childCells == null)
            {
                cells = null;
            }
            else
            {
                cells = new List<Cell>();
                foreach (XElement childCell in childCells)
                {
                    cells.Add(new Cell(childCell)); 
                }
            }
        }

    }
    public class Cell
    {
        public bool nil { get; set; }
        public int? m_ref {get;set;}
        public int? iD {get; set;}
        public Neighbor neighbor { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }

        public Cell(XElement cell)
        {
            XAttribute newNil = cell.Attributes().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "nil").FirstOrDefault();
            if (newNil == null)
            {
                nil = false;
            }
            else
            {
                nil = (cell.Value == "true")? true : false;
            }
            XAttribute newRef = cell.Attributes().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Ref").FirstOrDefault();
            if (newRef == null)
            {
                m_ref = null;
            }
            else
            {
                m_ref  = int.Parse(newRef.Value);
            }
            XAttribute newId = cell.Attributes().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Id").FirstOrDefault();
            if (newId == null)
            {
                iD = null;
            }
            else
            {
                iD = int.Parse(newId.Value);
            }
            XElement newState = cell.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "State").FirstOrDefault();
            if (newState == null)
            {
                state = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                state = newState.Value;
            }
            XElement newNeighbors = cell.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Neighbors").FirstOrDefault();
            if (newNeighbors == null)
            {
                neighbor = null;
            }
            else
            {
                neighbor = new Neighbor(newNeighbors);
            }

        }
    }
    public class Neighbor
    {
        public int? iD { get; set; }
        public int? size { get; set; }
        public int? version { get; set; }
        public Items items { get; set; }

        public Neighbor(XElement neighbor)
        {
            XAttribute newId = neighbor.Attributes().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Id").FirstOrDefault();
            if (newId == null)
            {
                iD = null;
            }
            else
            {
                iD = int.Parse(newId.Value);
            }
            XAttribute newSize = neighbor.Attributes().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Size").FirstOrDefault();
            if (newSize == null)
            {
                size = null;
            }
            else
            {
                size = int.Parse(newSize.Value);
            }
            version = int.Parse(neighbor.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "_version").FirstOrDefault().Value);

            XElement childItem = neighbor.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "_items").FirstOrDefault();
            if (childItem != null)
            {
                items = new Items(childItem);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue.
The problem was that I didn't have a "set" method for a DataMember property in the Universe class.
This caused the desialization to not be able to set it and throw an exception.

Thanks jdweng for trying to help.